# Why does my if statement not run even if the condition is met?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a simple program that asks the user a question and if the user answers correctly, it tells them that they are correct, but if they don't, it tells them to try again, and the code runs again. I did this using a while loop, if they answer correctly it breaks out of the while loop. But when i tested it even when i get the correct answer, it doesn't break out of the loop.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main() {
        int answer;
        while (1 < 2) {
            std::cout << "What is 3 + 5?";
            answer = std::cin.get();
            if (answer == 8) {
                std::cout << "You are correct!";
                break;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Wrong answer! Try again";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want `std::cin >> answer;`.

Comment: You might have printed `answer` to see the mismatch.

Comment: Some programmer dude is right, plus: If you press <8><enter> the next character in the input after the 8 is '\n', or '\r' under Windows. (Chances are you must press enter for the terminal to pass your input to the program, unless you did something fancy with your terminal setup before you ran the program.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function returns a *character*.

There is no existing encoding where the character `'8'` is equal to the integer `8`.

Either you need to convert the character to its corresponding integer:

```
(answer - '0') == 8
```

Or compare against the character:

```
answer == '8'
```

---

If you really want to read integers, then I suggest you read using the input operator `>>` instead:

```
std::cin >> answer;
```

Comment: Well, s/he may try to hit ctrl-h!

Comment: @ZXzedix I think the last suggestion, "reading integers", is what this use case would typically do. It discards all whitespace, including line breaks, which eliminates the surprises of reading raw terminal input.

Comment: An encoding is **not allowed** to exist where '8' is equal to 8.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should assign answer like that:

```
std::cin >> answer;
```

because get function gets the input as string and your answer variable is int.
So in the if statement, it checks `"8" == 8` and that returns false.
Concluding, the whole code must be like that:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int answer;
    while (1 < 2) {
        std::cout << "What is 3 + 5?";
        std::cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 8) {
            std::cout << "You are correct!";
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Wrong answer! Try again";
        }
    }
}
```